# How to create multiple profiles in android application?

Tags: android, profile

Can anyone tell me **How to create profiles for an android app?** Like when the user clicks on an existing profile, some parameters will be set accordingly, showing different contents. Can someone help me or guide me?

Comment: can you elaborate more something what exactly type of help you need? Have you tried something?

Comment: i am building a heart monitoring application. so i need to create multiple profile views for my app such that when the user clicks on a particular profile his age, gender,etc will be set and accordingly the heart rate result will be displayed saying if its normal or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.. Got your point.

If you don't know about database, first read [Sql Connectivity](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/sqlitedatabase-connectivity/).

Idea is, you can store all your information in database. Likewise, you can create 2 tables.
1st table is for users having their user names and `id`.
2nd table is related to data about their users and will have reference to their `ids` of 1st table.

Simple, when user login to their account, you get one `ID` which will used to fetch their age, sex, heart bit etc from other table.

Comment: okay thanks! will try this..i know how to store and update or delete data using SQLite. now need to fetch data using ID. good idea